# Azure Functions "Consumption Plan" HIPAA Compliance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Since Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events under "Consumption Plan", what is the guarantee that Azure transparently encrypts the data in-transit as well as at-rest on the hosts? Are there any documentations which can share some light on how Azure Functions fulfills HIPAA compliance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful not to conflate two separate things.  The plan type is not relevant to compliance.

Azure Functions are covered for HIPAA apps.  You can find the details here: [Overview of Microsoft Azure compliance](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Overview-of-Azure-c1be3942)

Note, Azure itself is baseline compliant.  But, you yourself can create and deploy an app that breaks compliance, just like you can on-prem.  Azure Functions are by nature stateless, but there's little stopping you, the developer, form persisting data in a non-compliant way.

Comment: Ok, so its our responsibility to encrypt the data in-transit as well at rest whenever using Azure Functions? 

I was hoping to find a functionality similar to Azure Blob Storage where data is encrypted transparently.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MohtashimShaikh Azure Function use TLS by default so you don't have to do anything, it's already encrypted...unless you specifically turn of this functionality.